# Can we loop Karate scenarios?

Tags: karate

I have a scenario with a POST request which uses JSON as request payload.
I need to run this scenario 10 times. I don't need to update the JSON, but just run the scenario 10 times.
Can I do this using Loop? If yes, how?

Here is my sample Karate test -

```
Scenario: post request to create users

* def payload = read('Payloads/createUser.json')

Given url  ' _____'
Then request payload 
When method POST
Then status 200
Then print response
```

thank you,

Comment: related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799845/442595

Answer (score 1):

You can call the same scenario again at the end of your statements:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callarray/call-json-array.feature

Scenario: Get status for any file type and print results
* url '___'
* method get
* print 'response: ' + response
* def status = response.output.status
* if (status == 'SUCCESS') karate.abort()
* print "retrying Ingestion Status Again"
* callonce read('ingestionStatus.feature') -- ingestionStatus.feature is this feature